# Can't access location from nginx config file

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to deploy an app through docker containers and reverse proxy it to my destination endpoint.

My docker compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  monitor.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}monitorapi
    ports:
     - "5001:443"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: monitor.API/Dockerfile  
  webapp:
     image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}monitorwebapp
     ports:
     - "4205:443"
     - "4206:80"
     build:
        context: ./monitor-webApp
        args:
        - BASE_API_URL=${BASE_API_URL}
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Both of the containers are getting built and running successfully. To access them I'm trying to set up a Nginx server with such config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <HOST IP>;

    sendfile on;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_comp_level 9;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location /monitorwebapp/ {
        proxy_pass http://<HOST IP>:4206/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /monitorapi/ {
        proxy_pass https://<HOST IP>:5001/api/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

So with that, my expectation, would be if I go to http://HOSTIP/monitorwebapp I should get my webapp. However, I'm only getting 404 and the only way for me to access it is through: http://HOSTIP:4206.

There is nothing in the error logs as well. Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: Your Nginx `location` ends with a slash, and I believe this matters; does `http://.../monitorwebapp/` with a trailing slash work?  (You might consider running the proxy in a container as well, which would save you from needing to know the host's IP address and wouldn't require you to publish the individual services' `ports:`.)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this wasn't it, even with or when I change the config to be without slashes, it doesn't work as expected